# Registry regedit not updating value C# process

Tags: c#, windows, registry, regedit

So I have a process running a `.reg` file (this file is large, it's not mine and it gets downloaded by the application)

The application appears to run and I see the registry refresh after it has run (it flashes) but then the key's are not updating

```cs
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "regedit.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/s \"" + InstallDirectory.Text + "\\FFNx.reg\"";
Console.WriteLine(proc.StartInfo.FileName+" "+proc.StartInfo.Arguments);
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

I have also tried, `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;` to see if that would make a difference the application is running as Administrator,

I have also tried to use `reg.exe` and arguments of `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "import \"" + InstallDirectory.Text + "\\FFNx.reg\"";`

This Regfile has both 64Bit and 32Bit keys inside it (so it includes both `Wow6432Node` and none versions of the keys, again i did not make this registry file)

If I run this exact command from cmd.exe running as admin it works perfectly

Even if I remove the `/s` argument and it asks the user the same thing happens. Regedit flashes like it's updated but then the values have not changed.

Comment: hmmm... did you try to hit F5 in regedit after your program ran?

Comment: @dba so i tried refreshing it, i also tried closing it and reopening it the value was not saved, when i do it from CMD i see it actively refresh and update in real time.

Comment: Is your app 32 bit or 64 bit? If it is 32 bit, it could start the 32 bit version of regedit.exe from the syswow64 folder. See [View the system registry by using 64-bit versions of Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/view-system-registry-with-64-bit-windows).

Comment: the app is set to Any CPU and prefer x64

Comment: One thing got me thinking... maybe you have a ```space``` in your path to the file..,. something like ```D:\Some Folder\FFNx.reg```. Which you need to add ```@``` to the beginning of the string. I have the same issue and it even notifies me that the registry key has been added but there is no key in the registry